# GZip compression in Contenful

Tags: gzip, contentful

My images coming from Contentful doesn't seems to be gzip compressed. Is there any setting that I need to make?

[This link](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/http-details/#gzip-compression) talks about that this is possible but I couldn't find any such setting. Can you please let me know how can I ensure that images I'm getting from Contentful cloudfront are gzip encoded?

Comment: Any help/suggestion anyone?

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for GZIP compression on images. GZIP and other compression algorithms only make sense for text-based formats. Images (and other binary formats) rely on different compression algorithms.

You can find more information here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/is-gzipping-images-worth-it-for-a-small-size-reduction-but-overhead-compressing

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Yeah, well.  _Most_ images are already compressed (e.g. `.gif`, `.png`, or `.jpg`) and on these the rather simple GZIP compression isn't very useful.  But there are other image format which aren't compressed, e. g. `.ppm`, and on these a GZIP compression would help quite a lot.